# How can I add documentation for my own custom steps to the snippet generator?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I create my own custom steps in my shared lib (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) which I use in my pipelines

```
#inside myCustomStep.groovy
def call(Map config) {
}
```

I can use them with the same syntax as actual plugin steps. But they do not appear in the snippet generator. The snippet generator is useful for reference and also for IDEs. This vscode extension actually reads that info off the jenkins master and uses it for autocompletion: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tabeyti.jenkins-jack

How do I get my custom steps created liek this into the snippet generator, is this possible?

Comment: Adding documentation for your global vars will add them to the global variables reference, and adding documentation for your library will add that to the steps reference, but I am unsure if either will automatically propagate to the snippet generator. You may want to put in a ticket for this.

Comment: I created help txt files but I dont see that info anywhere. If I create myStep.groovy and myStep.txt where do I see the help info in myStep.txt?

Comment: It will be in the global variable reference page in the Jenkins Pipeline page in your browser.